# ApplicationContext is not providing application.properties property source to the call back of ApplicationContextInitializer during /actuator/refresh

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Application context's Environment is not providing application.properties based property source to the call backs of implementations of ApplicationContextInitializer during /actuator/refresh end point call starting from spring boot 2.4.x & Spring cloud 2020.0.0.

This behaviour started with Spring Boot 2.4.x and Spring cloud 2020.0.0 and it is same till Spring Boot 3.0.x.

From Spring Boot 2.1.x to spring boot 2.3.x, we were getting application.properties based property source in the above said call back.

Call back method details here for spring boot 2.4.x: https://github.com/jk1608/springboot/blob/main/spring-boot-24-refresh/src/main/java/dev/demo/springboot24refresh/bootstrap/CustomApplicationContextInitializer.java

Test case that will fail with spring boot 2.4.x: https://github.com/jk1608/springboot/blob/main/spring-boot-24-refresh/src/test/java/dev/demo/springboot24refresh/main/SpringBoot24RefreshApplicationTest.java#L43

Test case that will pass with spring boot 2.1.x: https://github.com/jk1608/springboot/blob/main/spring-boot-21-refresh/src/test/java/dev/demo/springboot21refresh/main/SpringBoot21RefreshApplicationTest.java#L43

Complete problem description here: https://github.com/jk1608/springboot/blob/main/spring-boot-24-refresh/Readme.md

The complete minimal code to see this new behaviour with spring boot 2.4.x can be found here in github: https://github.com/jk1608/springboot/tree/main/spring-boot-24-refresh

The complete minimal code to see the old behaviour with Spring boot 2.1.x can be found here in github: https://github.com/jk1608/springboot/tree/main/spring-boot-21-refresh

Tried to find the root cause, but couldn't pin point to a particular change set in spring boot or spring cloud. Seems like it is framework level change, not sure though.

Before trying any solution, would like to know the root cause for this new behaviour in 2.4.x vs old behaviour in spring boot 2.1.x and whether it is really a bug or intentional behaviour and any recommendations around the same.

Any help around this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that 'bootstrap.*' files are refreshed fine. Taking this into consideration, I've come up with a workaround solution to this problem:

Rename all config files from `application.*` to `bootstrap.*`.

This way, Actuator will refresh your configuration.